# nginx alias to reflect in PHP_SELF (fpm)

Tags: nginx, php, lighttpd, mod-alias

I'm having a file structure like this:

nginx default root:

```
~/marketplace/
```

attempting to create an alias to:

```
~/marketplace/endpoints/sdk/tag.php
```

under URI location /tagframe.htm

Basically, when I go to http://marketplace/tagframe.htm?t=1&c=2 I need to route the request to ~/marketplace/endpoints/sdk/tag.php with the $query_string preserved

While this works:

```
location /tagframe.htm {
    try_files $uri /endpoints/sdk/tag.php$is_args$args;
}
```

It populates PHP_SELF with the actual path of the file (tag.php), and not URI part (tagframe.htm) which is what I need - for it to think that /tagframe.htm is a real file and populate it into PHP_SELF.

For example Lighttpd does it through its

```
alias.url /tagframe.htm => ~/marketplace/endpoints/sdk/tag.php
```

And PHP_SELF shows me /tagframe.htm

An attempt to trick it was:

```
location /tagframe.htm {
    alias $root_path/endpoints/sdk;

    rewrite (.*) /endpoints/sdk/tag.php?$query_string;

    include php-fpm;
}
```

P.S $root_path is my map default value of project root (hacky), php-fpm file is default fast_cgi proxy to php:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $host;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misusing PHP_SELF. It's intended to show [the actual script file name](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) that is running, not the URL.

What you seem to be looking for is REQUEST_URI, i.e.:

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
```

Comment: Would you like to explain where that variable fits into the config files above ??    No idea what to do with it currently.